# site is showing folder contents

Tags: codeigniter

I have hosted a site infinitiva.in built using codeigniter. It works fine on localhost but not on the server. Its giving a directory listing instead of showing the home page. I've modified htaccess and baseurl to my hosted domain. Please help...

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are missing your root `/index.php` file.

Confirm that it is there as I don't see it in the file listing:

```
Index of / 
 Name                    Last modified       Size  Description

 Parent Directory        02-Mar-2011 15:53      -  
 application/            03-Mar-2011 03:12      -  
 public/                 03-Mar-2011 02:53      -  
 system/                 03-Mar-2011 02:55      -  
 tmp/                    03-Mar-2011 03:12      -
```